# Razor view has some issues, what is wrong with this foreach calling a partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My razor view page looks like:

```
 @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
 {
           @Html.RenderPartial("Comment", comment);

 }
```

And my partial view is in /Shared/Comment.cshtml

```
@model Comment

<div>
<span class="user">@Model.Name</span>
...

</p>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

(it then highlights the call to @Html.RenderPartial("Comment", comment);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the '@' in front of Html since it is stated before any html:

```
 @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
 {
    Html.RenderPartial("Comment", comment);    
 }
```

Additionally, Html.RenderPartial doesn't return anything. So, it must be executed in a code block (the case above counts).

The @[some method] syntax is only valid for methods that return something that Razor can convert to a string.